# Why controler does not go in to Create function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have some custome section defined in seperate file, but when i call

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Group/Group1/screen1")
```

controler does not go in to Create method and above code return null, whats wrong? anything is missing ?

### web.Config:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="Group">
    <section name="Group1" type="Handler"
      allowLocation="true"
      allowDefinition="Everywhere">
    </section>      
  </sectionGroup>   
</configSections>
<Group>
   <Group1 configSource="folder1\custom.config" />    
</Group>
```

### Custom.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Group>
   <Group1>
     <Screen1>           
         <Property1>0</Property1>
         <Property2>1</Property2>
    </Screen1>
    <Screen2>
        <Property1>1</Property1>
        <Property2>Create</Property2>
    </Screen2>
   </Group1>   
   <Group2>
     <Screen1>           
         <Property1>0</Property1>
         <Property2>1</Property2>
    </Screen1>
    <Screen2>
        <Property1>1</Property1>
        <Property2>Create</Property2>
    </Screen2>
   </Group2>      
 </Group>
```

### Handler:

```
 public class Handler: IConfigurationSectionHandler
{        
    public object Create(object parent, object configContext, XmlNode section)
    {
         **debugger**
         // Some processing
        // return object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your custom.config should start at the `Group1` element, rather than the `Group` element, or the `configSource` should be applied to the `Group`. Either way, the root element of the referenced config file should be the same element type as `configSource` is applied to.

So, it sounds like what you want in your `web.config` is:

```
<Group configSource="folder1\custom.config" />
```

Whenever you use the `configSource`, the elements must match on both sides, e.g. if you have:

```
<Spargle configSource="place1.config" />
```

Then the *root* element of `place1.config` has to be a `<Spargle>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Spargle>
    <Floom/>
</Spargle>
```

Comment: If i create seperate config for each group (group1,group2,..)  then it works but i want one custom config so have added one root. As per your suggestion if i remove group elements it will throws run time error "config file is not in correct format".

Comment: @JeevanBhatt - I didn't suggest removing the group elements. I've updated my answer though.